# Updating mySQL database

Tags: java, php, json

When updating values into database, instead of updating 1 row each time(which is what we wanted), it update the whole database column.
Here are my codes:

Java code:

> ```
>   private Dialog alertDialog() {          final AlertDialog.Builder
> ```
>
> alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NotificationActivity.this);
>
> ```
>               // Setting Dialog Title
>               alertDialog.setTitle("Confirmation...");
>
>               // Setting Dialog Message
>               alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to accept this job?");
>
>               // Setting Icon to Dialog
>               alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
>
>               // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
>               alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
>                               // Write your code here to execute after dialog
>                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Accept", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                               // Return Result from alertdialog to database
>                               result = "accepted";
>                                System.out.println("The result is "+ result);
>                                new UpdateActivity().execute();
>                           }
>                       });
>               // Setting Negative "NO" Button
>               alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
>                               // Write your code here to execute after dialog
>                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reject", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                               dialog.cancel();
>                               // Return Result from alertdialog to database
>                               result = "rejected";
>                               System.out.println("The result is "+ result);
>                                new UpdateActivity().execute();
>                           }
>                       });
>               return alertDialog.show();      }
> ```
>
> /**  * Background Async Task to  update database  * */ class
>   UpdateActivity extends AsyncTask {
>
> /**      * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog    * */
>     @Override   protected void onPreExecute() {         super.onPreExecute();
>         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NotificationActivity.this);
>         pDialog.setMessage("Sending ...");
>         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
>         pDialog.show();     }
>
> /**      * Saving product    * */   protected String
>   doInBackground(String... args) {
>                 System.out.println("Sending...");
>
> ```
>   // getting updated data from dialog         String confirmation =
> ```
>
> result.toString();
>                 System.out.println("Result to string..." + confirmation );
>
> ```
>   // Building Parameters              List<NameValuePair> params = new
> ```
>
> ArrayList();   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ID,
>   uid));    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_RESULT, confirmation));
>             // getting JSON Object
>                 // Note that create product url accepts POST method
>                 JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(UPDATE_URL,
>                         "POST", params);
>                 System.out.println("Json parsing...");
>                     // check log cat fro response
>                 Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
>
> ```
>           // check for success tag
>           try {
>               System.out.println("Checking...");
>               int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
>
>               if (success == 1) {
>                   // successfully created product
>                   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), JobsAcceptedActivity.class);
>                   startActivity(i);
>                   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                   System.out.println("Successfully updated...");
>                   // closing this screen
>                   finish();
>               } else {
>                   // failed to create product
>                   //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update unsucessfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>                   System.out.println("Update unsuccessfully...");
>               }
>           } catch (JSONException e) {
>               e.printStackTrace();
>           }
>           System.out.println("Done!");
>
>           return null;            }
>
>       /**
>        * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
>        * **/          protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
>           // dismiss the dialog once done
>           pDialog.dismiss();          }
>
>   }   }
> ```

PHP code:

> $response = array();   // check for required fields if
>   (isset($_POST['UID']) && isset($_POST['accept'])) {
>
> ```
> $UID = $_POST['UID'];
> $accept = $_POST['accept'];
>
> // include db connect class
> require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
>
> // connecting to db
> $db = new DB_CONNECT();
>
> // mysql update row with matched pid
> $result = mysql_query("UPDATE notification SET accept = '$accept' WHERE UID = $UID");
>
> // check if column inserted or not
> if ($result) {
>     // successfully updated
>     $response["success"] = 1;
>     $response["message"] = "Notification successfully updated.";
>
>     // echoing JSON response
>     echo json_encode($response);
> } else {
>
> } } else {
> // required field is missing
> $response["success"] = 0;
> $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
>
> // echoing JSON response
> echo json_encode($response);
> ```

Comment: are you having duplicated rows ?. if not , then check whether the UID is sent from android code.

Answer (score 0):

Q:  When updating values into database, instead of updating 1 row each time(which is what we wanted), it update the whole database column.

A: It sounds like you probably want a more restrictive "where" clause on your update :)

Answer (score 0):

This is your one ==> $result = mysql_query("UPDATE notification SET accept = '$accept' WHERE UID = $UID");
My Suggession ==> $result = mysql_query("UPDATE notification SET accept = '$accept' WHERE UID = '$UID'"); or 
$queryString= "UPDATE notification SET accept = ".$accept." WHERE UID =".$UID;
$result = mysql_query($queryString);

Comment: both are the same . no differences !!